# function limit, Fourier transform, characteristic function

Tags: limits, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I want to show the following function limit satisfies
\begin{align}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{{x_m} \to 1} f({\bf x}) = 0\quad and \mathop {\lim }\limits_{{x_m} \to \infty} f({\bf x}) = 1
\end{align}
where \begin{align}
f({\bf x})=\int\limits_{0}^\infty  {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\prod\limits_{m = 0}^{M - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - 2jx_m w} }}\exp ( - jwt)} \frac{{dw}}{{2\pi }}dt} }
\end{align}
Maybe we can use some tricky ways, maybe some bounds, do you have some opinions, thank you so much.

Comment: Is product taken over $j$ instead of $m$? I also think the first limit should be 1 and the second 0, not the other way around.

Comment: No, the product is taken over $m$, why do you think the first one should be 1 and the second 0?

Comment: Your notations are difficult to understand. Are you taking limit with respect to one variable $x_m$ or with respect to $M$ variables? Is $j$ a constant?  Are you taking limit as each coordinate $\to \infty$ or the norm of the vector $\to \infty$ I say that second limit must be 0 because the integrand $\to 0$.